# Joining a table thru another property of another table that is linked with id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

**Edit : I did a mistake the Invoices Table carry the transactionId**

I have 3 tables :

```
Transactions  Reconciliations             Invoices
id            num    line transId         id   Code    transId
--            ---   ---- -------          --   ----    -------------
3              1    1    3                5   Code 5   3
6              1    2    6                9   Code 9   8    
7              1    3    7                12  Code 12  11
8              2    1    8
12             2    2    12
10             3    1    10
11             3    2    11
```

and this Query :

```
select
    t1.id   -- transaction id
    t2.num  -- reconciliation number
    t3.Code -- Invoice code
from Transactions t1
left outer join Reconciliations t2 on t2.transId = t1.id
left outer join Invoices t3 on t3.transId = t1.id
```

Giving the following result :

```
id      num     code
--     ---     ----
3       1       Code 5
6       1       null
7       1       null
8       2       Code 9
12      2       null
10      3       null
11      3       Code 12
```

But what I want is this :

```
id      num     code
--      ---     ----
3       1       Code 5
6       1       Code 5
7       1       Code 5
8       2       Code 9
12      2       Code 9
10      3       Code 12
11      3       Code 12
```

To put words on it when the linked Invoice table gives null I want to join on all the records from Reconciliations with the same Reconciliation number.

**Edit** : I would like **the Code in invoices to be shared across all transactions that shares the same Reconciliation number**

I have tried to do thru outer apply and sub query but I cannot figure out a way to achieve it. Have you any idea ?

Comment: did you mean `left outer join Invoices t3 on t3.id = t1.invoiceid`?

Comment: and what happens if there is more than one transaction that links from the reconciliation number to an invoice code?

Comment: There shouldn't be two different. If it has to happen it would be the same code.

Comment: OK, thanks. See my answer for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to join to `Reconciliations` *again* before joining to `Invoices`:

```
select t.id, r.num, i.Code
from Transactions t
join Reconciliations r on r.transId = t.id
join Reconciliations r2 on r2.num = r.num
join Invoices i on i.transId = r2.transId
```

Note that the joins are now *inner* joins (*requiring* a match), and how you easily make the connection to the right Invoice via the shared `Reconciliation.num` value - using inner joins means you only get the invoice row that matches.

To see this query in action, [execute it on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d149a/3)

---

#### Edit: To cater for missing invoices

Use  left join to invoices, but you need a group by with `max()` to limit the joins to just one invoice per transaction (without the `max()` you get lots of extra rows with null Code):

```
select t.id, r.num, max(i.Code) as Code
from Transactions t
join Reconciliations r on r.transId = t.id
join Reconciliations r2 on r2.num = r.num
left join Invoices i on i.transId = r2.transId
group by t.id, r.num
```

To see this query in action, where I have invalidated invoice 12 from above fiddle, [<kbd>execute it on SQLFiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d149a/5)

Comment: Dear Bohemian I just want to ask you do you have an idea how to do this assuming that there Can be null Reconciliations ? I mean is it possible do this with left outer join instead ?

Comment: No problem: See edits to answer for how to deal with missing invoices

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Awesome I managed to do it with an OUTER APPLY with an in statement but this is much better.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to spread the `InvoiceId` in `Transactions` up to the next value.

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
       (select top 1 InvoiceId
        from Transactions t2
        where t2.id <= t.id and t2.InvoiceId is not NULL
        order by id desc
       ) as newInvoiceId
from transactions t;
```

You can then substitute this into your query:

```
select
    t1.id   -- transaction id
    t2.num  -- reconciliation number
    t3.Code -- Invoice code
from (select t.*
            (select top 1 InvoiceId
             from Transactions t2
             where t2.id <= t.id and t2.InvoiceId is not NULL
             order by id desc
            ) as newInvoiceId
     from transactions t
    ) t1
left outer join Reconciliations t2 on t2.transid = t1.id
left outer join Invoices t3 on t3.id = t1.transid ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure this is correct I mean it is not necessarily to spread the Invoice Code up to the next value but to all transactions that shares the same Reconciliation number.

Comment: See my answer for comparison :)